# Validate if string has only numbers

Tags: java, regex, string, performance, parsing

My Java application 'A' is getting mobile number as String from another java application. So after app A gets the mobile number string, I need to validate if that mobile number String has only numbers in it. For validating that I have used a simple logic as below,

```
public static boolean containsOnlyDigits(String str, int n) {
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if (!Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i))) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I am checking from i=1 as 1st character will be '+' for country code. This approach is O(n). There is another approach where we can use `Double.parseDouble(str)`. This will throw `NumberFormatException` so that we can catch and consider it is an Alphanumeric String.

Which of these approaches are best based on performance?

Comment: in it's internals Double#parseDouble uses a loop with isDigit...But better write a JMH test to validate.

Comment: “This approach is O(n)” — Of course it is. What’s the problem?

Comment: @KonradRudolph I want to know if we can use Double.parseDouble instead of using our own implementation and it's performance impact.

Comment: @Sel_va I still don’t understand this objection since `Double.parseDouble` is **obviously** also running in O(n) (how could it not?!), and so is every other conceivable method.

Comment: Mobile phone numbers can contain all sorts of characters that are numbers, most notable the `+`´sign as you have noted. But also whitespace, parentheses, slashes, dashes and a few other things. Are you sure you need the string to be purely numeric?

Comment: @Sel_va - If one of the answers resolved your issue, you can help the community by marking that as accepted. An accepted answer helps future visitors use the solution confidently.

Answer (score 1):

You could try, remove the `+` if not useful:

```
 /**
 * Assuming that a phone number is of an international format, having `+` sign as prefix
 * and with no spaces in between the numbers, validates if a string is a valid phone number.
 * 
 * @param phone
 * @return resulting boolean
     */
private boolean isValidPhoneNumber(String phone) {
    if(phone == null) return false;
    
    return Pattern.matches("\\+\\d{11,15}", phone);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am checking from i=1 as 1st character will be '+' for country code.

You can use the regex, `\+\d{n - 1}` which means the first character is `+` and the remaining `n - 1` characters are digits. It also means that the total length of the string should be `n`.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Tests
        System.out.println(containsOnlyDigits("+123456789", 10));
        System.out.println(containsOnlyDigits("+123456789", 9));
        System.out.println(containsOnlyDigits("+123456789", 8));
        System.out.println(containsOnlyDigits("-123456789", 9));
        System.out.println(containsOnlyDigits("123456789", 9));
        System.out.println(containsOnlyDigits("ABC123456", 9));
    }

    public static boolean containsOnlyDigits(String str, int n) {
        String regex = "\\+\\d{" + (n - 1) + "}";
        return str.matches(regex);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
true
false
false
false
false
false
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expressions is costly. For this reason, you can easily solve this problem using the lambda notation in Java 8.

```
boolean numericControl = str.chars().allMatch(x -> Character.isDigit(x));
```

Comment: Using regex isn’t *that* costly, especially with a precompiled regex, and it’s a perfectly appropriate solution for text input validation. In fact, creating streams is *also* costly.